# Jinja2 not work on flask/glitch.me deployment

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, web-deployment

I have [a deployment of a tiny Flask app](https://prettymes.glitch.me/templates) on Glitch. It seems to be working... sort of. However, the Jinja2 template engine is clearly not working, since all Jinja2 tags are being read into the browser as text. The application, which I have up [on my GitHub page](https://github.com/bronzebygold/prtty_mes), works fine on the localhost. Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions where we have to click into multiple links you provide. Please give an example code where it is not working.

Comment: @Algorithman How would I do that in this case? The question is about an unusual behavior encountered after deploying on Glitch. The code itself works fine on localhost. Can you give me an example of how I would simplify the problem for you?

Comment: Please choose the right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was not a problem with earlier [versions](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2127#issuecomment-360269773) of Flask and Python.

---

**Firstly**, adding the following  `debug`  option in the  `server.py`  file.

`app.debug = True`

**Secondly**, add some code as follows:

`@app.after_request
def apply_kr_hello(response):
    """Adds some headers to all responses."""

    ...
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache' 
    return response`

**Thirdly**, do a  `Ctrl-Shift-R`  on the specific browser tab where your application is being rendered.

That is it! Now, when you make changes to static file, they should be reflected in your app.

I presume one might also benefit from reading https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-flask as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python expert but while your glitch [project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/prettymes?path=mesostic.py:17:32) has the same code as localhost, your local machine is executing the code through a different path. In this case because there are no instructions for Glitch to start your project from `mesostic.py` it's just treating your project as a static website. (hence why the template tags are just being rendered out as text).

It might help to look at other python projects on glitch to get a sense of how to execute your `.py` file. e.g. checkout `start.sh` on https://glitch.com/edit/#!/python3-morepath. I'm not sure but you may also need a `requirements.txt` to tell Glitch that this is a python project.

Hope this gives you a place to start debugging from